# cannot get correct password format

Tags: java, passwords, character

I want to create an application that asks the user to enter password from input dialogs.The password must be less than 10 characters and more than 6 characters.Also,the password should contain at least one digit or letter. When the password meets all the requirements,ask user to enter password again and do not let the user continue until the second password matches the first one.
My code is as follows but it is not checking the letter or digit.
Can anyone help?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password{

public static void main(String[] args){

String firstPassword="";
String secondPassword="";

char charChecked;

boolean letter = false;
boolean digit = false;

int len=firstPassword.length();

firstPassword= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ENter");

if (( len<6 || len>10) || ! (Character.isLetterOrDigit(firstPassword.charAt(len))) )

{firstPassword= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Correct Format of password");
}


if ((len>=6|| len<=10) || (Character.isLetterOrDigit(firstPassword.charAt(len))) )
do
{
secondPassword= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter again the password to confirm");
}
while (!(firstPassword.equals(secondPassword)));
if (firstPassword.equals(secondPassword))
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Accepted");
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int len=firstPassword.length();

firstPassword= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ENter");
```

your code are inverted... you need to call the length after input something.

```
firstPassword= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ENter");
int len=firstPassword.length();
```

Try and say something...

Comment: I corrected that.It is not working and throwing me out of bound exception.I think there is an error with "(Character.isLetterOrDigit(firstPassword.charAt(len)"

Comment: Sorry for just answer now... but yes, cause you're trying to compare with the last position.
For you see if your password has or not a letter or a digit you would need a cicle.
For( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
{
 if( character.isletterordigit(firstPassword.charat( i ) )
{...}
}
/* for example... */